# Graphical Representation of Relational Categorical Variables

Tags: python, r, ggplot2

I'm seeking some ideas to better illustrate the relationship between categorical variables.

**For the reproducible data I have below:**

```
t1 <- data.frame(A = c("Apple", "Rose, Apple", "Country"), 
                 B = c("Fruit", "Plant", "Peru, Japan"))
```

**Output**

```
            A           B
1       Apple       Fruit
2 Rose, Apple       Plant
3     Country Peru, Japan
```

You can see that Apple is related to fruit and plant. Is there a good graphical solution to colour display the respective variables in a heatmap format?

Comment: At least to me, your question is fairly vague; a heatmap is a visual representation of *numeric* data in a grid/matrix layout. Based on your sample data, what numeric values are you expecting to show in such a heatmap? Perhaps it would help if you were to provide a mock-up plot. Your data structure also seems somewhat odd. `Peru, Japan` in column B are *examples* of `Country` in column A, but `Apple` in column A is an *example* of `Fruit` in column B. So somehow it seems that entries in columns A and B are swapped. Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I would think of something like this:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(type = as.factor(c("Apple", "Rose", "Apple", "Rose", "Apple")),
                 type2 = as.factor(c("Fruit", "Plant", "Plant", "Tree", "Tree")))
```

First we got a table with the different combinations:

```
dt 
    type type2
1: Apple Fruit
2:  Rose Plant
3: Apple Plant
4:  Rose  Tree
5: Apple  Tree
```

Then we got some stats (counts and relative percentage):

```
dt2 <- dt[ , .(count = .N), by = .(type, type2)]

dt2[ , percentage.count := count / sum(count) * 100 , by = "type"]

dt2

    type type2 count percentage.count
1: Apple Fruit     1         33.33333
2:  Rose Plant     1         50.00000
3: Apple Plant     1         33.33333
4:  Rose  Tree     1         50.00000
5: Apple  Tree     1         33.33333
```

Where we could see that `apple` was related `1/3` of times with `Fruit`, `1/3` of times with `Plant` and `1/3` of times with `Tree`.

That could be plotted like this:

```
ggplot(data = dt2,
       aes(x = type, fill = type2)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

[image]

This is just like having a "pie" of how many rows with the same `type`-`type2` combinations we have, but at least is something to see which types are more related than others.